Cannot access 'React' before initialization while using rollup manualChunks with vitejs?
I'm using vitejs for bundling.
This is the manualChunks part of rollupOptions in my vite.config.js:
{
  output : {
    if( id.includes( 'node_modules/react/' ) || id.includes( '/node_modules/react-dom' ) ) {
      return 'react';
    }

    if( id.includes( '@emotion' ) ) {
      return 'emotion';
    }
  }
}

I's working well till after running vite build. But I got a error message in browser console while opening the webpage:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'React' before initialization
    at emotion-CgLvcQ7O.js:1255:26



Seems to be a bug in Vite https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/12209. Hopefully fixed soon
